# Round table. What's the probability that boy/girl alternate.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Ten boys and ten girls are sitting at a round table. What is the probability that children would alternate: boy, girl, boy, girl?

Solution:
It's clear that children can be arranged in 19! ways. Now count the ways to place children alternately. There are $\frac{10!^2}{20}$ to do it. I divide by 20 due to circular symmetry. So, the answer is $\frac{10!^2}{20!}$.

Am i right with my solution?

Comment: There are $20$, not $10$, places to place the first boy. Not taking circular symmetry into account prob is $\frac{20*9!10!}{20!}=\frac{9!10!}{19!}$. Taking circular symmetry into account fix the first child.  There are $9$ spots for the other children of that gender and $10$ spots for those of the other gender.  So prob is $\frac {9!10!}{19!}$. .... Alternatively there are ${20\choose 10}$ ways to choose seats for the boys and $2$ of those are alternating and it doesn't matter how you arrange individually. So prob is $\frac{2}{20\choose 10}=\frac{2*10!10!}{20!}=\frac{9!10!}{19!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Almost.  Your only error was in estimating there where $10!$ ways to seat boys alternately and $10!$ to seat the girls.  The first boy (or girl) has $20$, not $10$ choices of seats so it is actually $20*9!10!$ rather than $10!10!$*.

If you are doing probability it doesn't matter if you take circular symmetry into account or not as long as you do it consistently.

Given seats $1-20$ there are $20!$ ways to place the the kids and to place them alternately there are $20$ places to put the first boy, and $9$ for the second an so on.  There are $20*9!10!$ ways to place to place alternating  boys and girls so the prob is $\frac {20*9!10!}{20!}$.

That's without taking symmetry into account.  If you take symmetry into account.  there are $19!$ ways to do the kids.  And $9!$ ways to place the other $9$ children of the same gender as the child in the top position alternately and $10!$ ways to place the other gender.   So the prob is $\frac {9!10!}{19!}$.

Also if you ignore symmetry and the individual placing of individual children.  There are ${20\choose  10} = \frac {20!}{10!10!}$ ways to place the ten boys and $2$ of them are alternating.  SO the probability is $\frac 2{\frac {20!}{10!10!}}$

And you take symmetry into account by not the idiividual ways of placing children, There are ${19\choose 9}$ ways to choose places for the remaining $9$ of the top gender, or equally ${19\choose 10}$ ways to choose places for the other gender.  And only one of those is alternating.  SO the probability is either $\frac 1{19\choose 9} = \frac 1{\frac{19!}{9!10!}}$ or $\frac 1{19\choose 10} = \frac 1{\frac {19!}{10!9!}}$.

Hopefully it is clear that all of those yield the same answer.